# LoL API, accesing the json structure

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to consume the League of Legends API with a simple SUMMONER SEARCH BY NAME example with Angular and JavaScript.

This is my search method

```
if($scope.search === undefined){
$scope.search = "mainumby";
fetch();
}
```

and this is my request and response

```
function fetch(){
var url = "https://las.api.pvp.net/api/lol/las/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"+ $scope.search + "?api_key=" + API_KEY;
//console.log(url);
$http.get(url)
.success(function(response){
//first try
console.log("res:",response);
//second try
console.log("res:",response.mainumby);

$scope.details = response.mainumby;
});

}
```

the parameter **response** receives the json structure correctly

```
res: Object {mainumby: Object}mainumby: Objectid: 62075name: "Mainumby"profileIconId: 578revisionDate: 1390173606000summonerLevel: 30 }}
```

My question is, if **$scope.details** just receives **response** i can´t get access to the members, but if I use **response.mainumby** it´s OK and my html+angular works

```
res: Object {id: 62075, name: "Mainumby", profileIconId: 578, summonerLevel: 30, revisionDate: 1390173606000}
```

and put it on my html

```
<p>{{ details.id }}</p>
<p>{{ details.name }}</p>
<p>{{ details.profileIconId }}</p>
<p>{{ details.summonerLevel }}</p>
<p>{{ details.revisionDate }}</p>
```

Obviously I can´t use this hardcoding **response.mainumby** for another summoner search, so how can I can avoid this? How should I properly use the json I receive?

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with angular, but can you try this:
var userName = "mainumby";  $scope.search = userName ;... $scope.details = response[userName];

Comment: Hi, I tried what you say and got a udefine result  with console.log("res:",response[userName]); when i try i new search. :/

Comment: Can you update your example with what you've tried per Ziv's suggestion?

Comment: Also, I'd recommend using the $resource factory instead of $http.   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: This post isn't exactly related but take a look at it for a simplified example of making a ReST api call: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440964/angularjs-jquery-ajax-form-submission-equivalent/29441219#29441219

Comment: I believe this will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648480/how-do-i-get-the-specific-value-from-json-data-using-angularjs

Comment: @dmcqu314 I'll give a look at this, and will post with the results.